# Using the least squares method for problems with two independent variables

Tags: optimization, least-squares

This may be quite a specific question and I apologise however I have struggled to find any information regarding a method.

I have 6 given $P_i$ values and 6 given $E_i$ and $F_i$ values and I want to find the "best" values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ which give the minimum of $\sum_{i=1}^6 (P_i - a - b E_i - c F_i)^2$.

I have been trying to use the 'least squares' method by plugging in all data in the model to get an over-determined linear system of equations but I can't get the data into matrix form, i.e. $Ax=b$  to solve $A^TAx=A^Tb$.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. (I've edited this post for you as an example.) As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: +1 for using, on your first question, absolutely proper formatting of all you equations!

Answer (score 1):

The symmetric matrix  $A$ you form has row and column indices corresponding to the terms in the fit; in this case, the coefficients of $E$, $F$, and $1$, or $b$, $c$ and $a$. The column matrix $b$ also has rows with these same indices.  The specific formula is
$$
A = \pmatrix{
\sum_i 1\cdot 1 = n & \sum_i 1 \cdot E_i & \sum_i 1 \cdot F_i \\
\sum_i E_i\cdot 1 = \sum_i E_i & \sum_i E_i \cdot E_i = \sum_i E_i^2 & \sum_i E_i \cdot F_i \\
\sum_i F_i\cdot 1 = \sum_i F_i & \sum_i F_i \cdot E_i & \sum_i  F_i^2 \\
}
$$
and the column vector on the right is
$$
b = \pmatrix{ \sum_i P_i \\ \sum_i E_iP_i\\ \sum_i F_iP_i}
$$
Done in this way, the equations are not overdetermined, and unless you are unlucky enough to have $\mbox{det } A = 0$ there is a unique best-fit solution for $x = (a,b,c)^T$, obtained by solving
$$
Ax = b
$$